# Why wont my css change my div?

Tags: html, css

I am making a simple website and the writing I did in html in my div is showing up but the CSS is not effecting it.(ex. no colored box is showing up.)

this is the html

```
<div id=“hello”>hello</div>
```

this is the css

```
#hello {
background:#ccc;
width:200px;
height:200px;
}
```

this is the full code

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title</title>
     <meta charset="UTF-8">
     <title>Website</title>
  <meta name="author" content="WebDev">
     <link href="example.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
  <style>

  html { 
 font-family: "Open Sans";
    font-size: 24px;
    font-style: light;
    font-variant: normal;
    font-weight: 500;
    line-height: 26.4px;
}
}
body { 
 background:#Fff; margin:0 ;
}
#container { 
 width:1300px; 
 margin:0 auto; 
 background:#iff; 
}

#header { 
 width:100%; 
 height:170px; 
 background:#Fff;
 }

#logo { 
 float:left; 
 width:400px; 
 height:40px; 
 margin:30px; 
 background:#Fff;
 color: #000;
 font-size: 40px;
 line-height:38px; 
}
span1 { font-size: 30px;
        line-height: 18px;


}
#navbar { 
 height:40px; 
 clear:both; 
 background: #Fff;
}
#navbar ul { 
 margin:10px; 
 padding:1px; 
 list-style-type:none;
 line-height: 40px; 
}
#navbar ul li { 
 padding:px; 
 float:right ; 
 margin-top:20px;
}
#navbar ul li a { 
 font-size:24px; 
 float:right ; 
 float:right ;
 padding:0 0 0 20px; 
 display:block;
 text-decoration:none;
 font-weight:100;
 color:#000;
}


#banner { 
 background-image: url(pics/babypic.png);
 background-repeat: no-repeat;
 background-size:100%;
 height:445px; 
 padding:20px;
 clear: both;
}


#left_col { 
 float:left; 
 width:819px; 
 padding:20px; 
 height:600px; 
 color:#000; 
 background:#F0F8FF;
 font-size:20px;
}
h1 {
 font-size:35px;
 text-align:center;
 font-weight:300;
 margin-top:50px;
}
p {
 font-size:25px;
 font-weight: 200;
 margin-right:75px;
 margin-left:90px;
 line-height:40px;
 margin-top:50px;
}


#right_col { 
 float:right; 
 width:400px; 
 height:600px;  
 color:#000; 
 background:#F0F8FF; 
 padding:20px; 
}
h2 {
 font-size:35px;
 text-align:right;
 font-weight:400;
 margin-right:75px;
}
h3 {
 font-size:25px;
 font-weight: 200;
 margin-right:70px;
 margin-left:50px;
 line-height:40px;
 margin-top:30px;
 text-align:right;
}
#hello {
   height: 200px;
   width: 200px;
   background-color:#ccc;
}
#footer { 
 height:450px;
 background:#F0F8FF;
 float:bottom;
 clear:both;
 font-weight:100;
 font-size:25px;
} 
h5 {
 font-weight:100;
 font-size:25px;
 margin-left:250px;
 margin-right:250px;
 line-height:40px;
}
#footer ul1 {
 margin-left:400px;
 list-style:none;
 width:40%;
 display:block;
}


h4 {
 text-align:center;
 margin: 70px;
 font-weight:;
}

#end {
 height:200px;
}

  </style>
</head>
<body>
<!-- container -->
 <div id="container">
 <!--  header -->
 <div id="header">
  <div id="logo">
James Brewer, M.D. <span1> santa barbara pediatrician </span1>
</div>
  <div id="navbar">
   <ul>
    <li><a href="#">contact </a></li>
    <li><a href="#">gallery &nbsp;|</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">fees & insurance &nbsp;|</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">hours & location&nbsp; |</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">services &nbsp;|</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">about &nbsp; |</a></li>
   </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
  <!-- content area -->
  <div id="content_area">
   <div id="banner"></div>
   <div id="left_col">
<h1>
What People Are Saying
</h1>
<p>
“Thank you so much for your kindness and support. We sincerely appreciate your assistance and professional courtesy” —C.S
</p>
<p>
“He is very understanding, explaining things very well and has patience with kids. I highly recommend him. —C.G
</p>
<p>
“Thank you so much for your guidance and wisdom.” —K.R
</p>
</div>
   <div id="right_col">
<h2>
Call Us Today!   
</h2>
<h3>
set up an appointment 
<p2>  1-805-563-0167
</p2>
</h3>
<div id=“hello”>hello</div>
  </div>
 <!-- blurb area -->
 <!-- footer -->
  <div id="footer">

<h5>
Dr. Brewer has been practicing pediatrics in Santa Barbara since 2002. 
The office is a solo practice–patients always see Dr. Brewer. <p>
The practice offers:</p>
</h5>
<ul1>
<li>•newborn hospital care</li>
<li>•well child care</li>
<li>•school, camp and sports physicals</li>
<li>•acute sick visits</li>
<li>•immunizations </li>
<li>•lab testing</li>
<li>•developmental or behavioral concerns</li>
</ul1>
</div>
</div>
 <div id=end>
<h4>
<p>2421 Bath Street, Suite A
</p><p>
Call for an appointment today 
1-805-563-0167 
</p>
</h4>
</div>
 </div><!-- end container -->
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: it also should show up on top of another div. I don't know if that effects anything but..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The double quotes you are using around the "hello" are different than everywhere else in the HTML.

**If you re-type those double quotes it'll work.**

Here is how the quotes look like to the browser. 
1) Shows how "hello" shows up in a code editor but 2) and 3) show what the browser sees. Notice the extra pair of "? Tricky!

[image]

**DEMO of the problem**

```css
#hello {
  height: 200px;
  width: 200px;
  background-color: #ccc;
}
```

```html
<h3>BAD HELLO</h3>
<div id=“hello”>hello</div>

<h3>GOOD HELLO</h3>
<div id="hello">hello</div>
```

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH! This saved me! I have been struggling with this for hours! I never would have noticed that!

Answer (score 4):

There's just a *little* error in your div: If you look closely at the quotes around "hello" and the other quotes in your HTML file, they're not the same kind of quotes!

In the Firefox debugging tools [(image)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/u52AF.jpg), you can see that this causes the browser to interpret the class of the div incorrectly.

```
<div id=“hello”>hello</div>
```

vs

```
<div id="hello">hello</div>
```

Here's what your HTML looks like when it's fixed! (Just make the quotes different)

[final_image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NgrKY.jpg)

(Disclaimer: I just signed up on the site so my reputation isn't high enough to create in-post images :P, sorry about that)

Comment: its fine! i don't know how the different quotes work though. How do I fix it? They automatically change

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: I haven't used TextEdit before but I see that if you go to the Edit | Substitutions menu item and toggle off "Smart Quotes" then you won't get this auto-correcting of double quotes. This editor doesn't look to me to be one that is good for coding. My favourite (and many others) is Visual Studio Code. https://code.visualstudio.com/ It's free and runs on all platforms, Mac included. Highly recommended to use that editor instead.

Answer (score 0):

try to give it width and height..

```
    div {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
    background-color:blue;
}
```

Comment: i added dimensions and no luck

Answer (score 0):

Make sure to link the HTML file to the CSS file. You do that by adding a `link` tag to the top of the HTML file, like this:

```
<link type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="style.css" />
```

Where `style.css` is, you should write the path to your CSS file.

Comment: i just did a section that had <style> at the beginning and </style> at the end.